# JSON name value pair Parsing in Java

Tags: java, json

I have following JSON structure which i want to parse into Java objects. Are there existing libraries which I can use, or should I write custom code to parse. Sample json structure and java classes are below.

JSON:

```
"name": "hierarchy",
"value": "[
  {
    "name": "solutionid",
    "value": "String"
  },
  {
    "name": "groupcode",
    "value": "String"
  },
  {
    "name": "dealhashid",
    "value": "String"
  },
  {
    "name": "keyinfo_customername",
    "value": "String"
  },
  {
    "name": "keyinfo_prequalificationnumber",
    "value": "String"
  },
  {
    "name": "keyinfo_orderactiontype",
    "value": "String"
  }
]"
```

Java Object:

```
class Hierarchy {
    String solutionId;
    String groupCode;
    KeyInfo keyInfo;

    public String getSolutionId() {
        return solutionId;
    }

    public void setSolutionId(String solutionId) {
        this.solutionId = solutionId;
    }

    public String getGroupCode() {
        return groupCode;
    }

    public void setGroupCode(String groupCode) {
        this.groupCode = groupCode;
    }

    public KeyInfo getKeyInfo() {
        return keyInfo;
    }

    public void setKeyInfo(KeyInfo keyInfo) {
        this.keyInfo = keyInfo;
    }
}

class KeyInfo {
    String customerName;
    String orderActionType;

    public String getCustomerName() {
        return customerName;
    }

    public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }

    public String getOrderActionType() {
        return orderActionType;
    }

    public void setOrderActionType(String orderActionType) {
        this.orderActionType = orderActionType;
    }
}
```

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: please refer this link http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/ . very good examples 5th one is for you.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: It's off-topic, but as a clue, google Jackson or Gson

Answer (score 2):

Use a [Gson lib](https://github.com/google/gson)

1. Define a Pojo

```
class Pojo {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Pojo [name=" + name + ", value=" + value + "]";
    }

    private String name;
    private List<Value> value;
}

class Value {

    private String name;
    private String value;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Value [name=" + name + ", value=" + value + "]";
    }

}
```

2. Parse the string to a pojo object:

```
String json = "{\"name\": \"hierarchy\",\"value\": [  {    \"name\": \"solutionid\",    \"value\": \"String\"  },"
                + "           {    \"name\": \"groupcode\",    \"value\": \"String\"  },  {    \"name\": \"dealhashid\",    \"value\": \"String\""
                + "           },  {    \"name\": \"keyinfo_customername\",    \"value\": \"String\"  },  {    \"name\": \"keyinfo_prequalificationnumber\","
                + "         \"value\": \"String\"  },  {    \"name\": \"keyinfo_orderactiontype\",    \"value\": \"String\"  }]}";

Gson g = new Gson();
Pojo p = g.fromJson(json, Pojo.class);
System.out.println(p);
```

---

## no Pojo Edit:

```
String json = "{\"name\": \"hierarchy\",\"value\": [  {    \"name\": \"solutionid\",    \"value\": \"String\"  },"
                + "           {    \"name\": \"groupcode\",    \"value\": \"String\"  },  {    \"name\": \"dealhashid\",    \"value\": \"String\""
                + "           },  {    \"name\": \"keyinfo_customername\",    \"value\": \"String\"  },  {    \"name\": \"keyinfo_prequalificationnumber\","
                + "         \"value\": \"String\"  },  {    \"name\": \"keyinfo_orderactiontype\",    \"value\": \"String\"  }]}";

Gson g = new Gson();
JsonObject p = g.fromJson(json, JsonObject.class);
System.out.println(p.get("name"));
System.out.println(p.get("value"));
```

now you can play with the name and the value...

Comment: but then i should write custom code to convert from Pojo to Hierarchy class.. i want to avoid that..